# Getting raw XML response from Java web service client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, rad

I am trying to get the raw XML response from a web service, instead of the usual set of POJOs.

I am using a webservice client that I generated (so I have access to the client's code) from a WSDL and some schemas. The client is generated in RAD 7.5, I think using JAX-WS. I've been looking at the client code itself, but I'm not even sure if the client code ever handles raw XML or if it passes it off to other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using

```
javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler<javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext>
```

you can simply get message using `SOAPMessageContext#getMessage()` and convert message to String using method

```
   public static String getXmlMessage(SOAPMessage message) throws Exception
   {
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         message.writeTo(os);
         final String encoding = (String) message.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING);
         if (encoding == null)
         {
             return new String(os.toByteArray());
         }
         else
         {
            return new String(os.toByteArray(), encoding);    
         }
   }
```

Also you can read here about SOAP handler on client side
[Article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-client-side/)

Comment: Ok, though I'm not sure how I can return this string back to my main application.

Comment: I am using this construction in my project for print request/response in logs.

Comment: You can create global variable ArrayList, and put all String to it

Comment: That's going to be a little awkward in my situation. Is there a more graceful way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not widely documented, but you can use the [Dispatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.html) interface to implement JAXWS clients which work directly w/ the XML.  [Here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/9.0.5?topic=services-developing-jax-ws-clients) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-zos/9.0.5?topic=clients-developing-dynamic-client-using-jax-ws-apis) are some articles for getting started.

Comment: Two last links like broken.