# Is it possible to get the raw XML payload using Metro web services framework?

Tags: xml, tomcat, logging, java-metro-framework

I'm writing a web service client that runs in Apache Tomcat. I need to get the XML payload for the request/response so that I can log it.

Dumping the bytes to stdOut is not what I want. I want to get it as bytes in my Java code, so that I can log it the way that I want.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is one of main purposes of JAX-WS handlers. You will not get XML payload as raw bytes, but formatted; however if you want it is easy to turn it into raw bytes again. An example:

```
public class MyCustomHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        SOAPEnvelope env = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = env.getBody(); 
        // now when you have SOAP body you can do whatever you want...
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also use this call:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Object payload = msg.getPayload(jaxbContext);
```

References:

- [JAX-WS : SOAP handler in server side](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/)
- [Adding JAX-WS handlers to web services and SOAP clients](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/jaxws_handler_tutorial)

Comment: Thanks Miljen, I'll test and post back here what I find.

Comment: @JesseBarnum You are welcome. Hope that this will resolve your problem.