# Getting raw XML from a webservice request without SOAPHandler

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to get the raw XML from a web service request. Searching in google and stackoverflow I find a solution that seems good:

[Getting raw XML response from Java web service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976234/getting-raw-xml-response-from-java-web-service-client)

but my problem is that I don't have the library of the SOAPHandler available. There's something else I can do to achive my purpose without implementing the SOAPHandler? (May be with a more general Handler?)

Thank you.